# Image button in android pressed and get a random image in an array sequentially

Tags: java, android, imagebutton, android-imagebutton

```js
public abstract class MainActivity extends Activity  implements View.OnClickListener{

    private ImageButton bt1;
    public int index =0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Drawable[][] images = new Drawable[4][16];
        bt1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.im_bt1);
        bt1.setImageDrawable(images[index][(int)(Math.random()*16)]);
        bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                index++;
                ((ImageButton)v).setImageDrawable(images[index][(int)(Math.random()*16)]);

            }
        });

    }


    Red RR1 = new Red(R.drawable.rr1);
    Red RY1 = new Red(R.drawable.ry1);
    Red RG1 = new Red(R.drawable.rg1);
    Red RB1 = new Red(R.drawable.rb1);
    Green GB1 = new Green(R.drawable.greenblue);
    Green GG1 = new Green(R.drawable.greengreen);
    Green GR1 = new Green(R.drawable.greenred);
    Green GY1 = new Green(R.drawable.greenyellow);
    Yellow YY1 = new Yellow(R.drawable.yellowyellow);
    Yellow YB1 = new Yellow(R.drawable.yellowblue);
    Yellow YG1 = new Yellow(R.drawable.yellowgreen);
    Yellow YR1 = new Yellow(R.drawable.yellowred);
    Blue BR1= new Blue(R.drawable.br1);
    Blue BB1=new Blue(R.drawable.bb1);
    Blue BY1=new Blue(R.drawable.by1);
    Blue BG1= new Blue(R.drawable.bg1);

    Red[] Redarray = new Red[]{
            RR1,RY1,RG1,RB1
    };
    Green[] Greenarray = new  Green[]{
            GR1,GB1,GY1,GG1
    };

    Blue[] Bluearray = new  Blue[]{
      BB1,BY1,BG1,BR1
    };

    Yellow[] Yellowarray = new Yellow[]{
            YB1,YG1,YR1,YY1
    };


}
```

I have an `ImageButton` in my layout and I want to press the button and get another random `ImageButton` from an array and the get another when I press that one, but I want it to show sequentially on the arrays that I made.

array of images 1
array of images 2
array of images 3
array of images 4

Image Button from `array1` to another random Image Button from `array2`  to another Image Button from `array 3`...

edit: so I made a class of all the arrays and it's not working.. I'm struggling to make an array of arrays.. can u guys check my code? thanks..

Comment: Please post some code showing what you've tried, and we can try and show you what changes you need to make to get it to work.

Comment: alright thanks! i'll get an update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you were never resetting the index variable. You could solve like

```
...
final Random random = new Random();
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    bt1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.im_bt1);
    bt1.setImageDrawable(randomFromArray(images[index]));

    bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (++index == 4) {
                // reset index if it is too high after increment
                index = 0;
            }
            ((ImageButton) v).setImageDrawable(randomFromArray(images[index]));
}

public <T> T randomFromArray(final T[] array) {
    return array[random.nextInt(array.length)];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First: I would not change to another ImageButton everytime, but rather just change the displayed image.

Second: You need an array of arrays of ImageButtons (or drawables).
Then you need an index for your outer array and need a random value for your inner array.

```
Drawable[][] images = new Drawable[4][10]; //your 4 outer arrays with 10 drawables to choose randomly from // needs to be a member variable
fillArray();//add your drawables to the arrays here
int index = 0;//needs to be a member variable too
ImageButton button = new ImageButton(this);
button.setImageDrawable(images[index][(int)(Math.random()*10)]);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    index++;
        ((ImageButton)v).setImageDrawable(images[index][(int)(Math.random()*10)]);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! did you mean I can click only one image button  as much as I want and get to display multiple images?

Comment: *get to display multiple images in the same button* and do I have to create an xml file for it?